# How to calculate change in orientation on an iphone around 3 axis?

Tags: ios, xcode, motion, motion-detection

In most of the phones that uses android OS contains orientation sensor which forms a part of motion events. These sensors output the change in the orientation of the device at interval rate set by the user. But iphone doesnt have any orientation sensor, So how can i establish this task in an iphone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you could use the gyroscope to get the phone's orientation in space and alter your application accordingly, but I have not tried anything like that so I don't know too much about how possible performance-wise.

Here is the CMMotionManager Class Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope that helps!